# Memory heap increases when Chrome tab is inactive

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, highcharts, tabs, setinterval

Using React and HighCharts to build a dashboard refreshed every 10 seconds using setInterval.

- when browser tab is active there is no memory heap problem.
- when browser tab is inactive there is a constant increase in the memory heap.
- when open back up the tab there is an instant drop in the memory heap.

The real problem is that my web application freezes when tab is left inactive for too long.

A screenshot of the memory heap:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

It looks this is is the problem:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs

Chrome doesn't call `requestAnimationFrame()` when tab is inactive.

How do people solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dashboard can't be seen, there really isn't a need to update it. If chrome has this issue, I'd recommend just updating it once on re-focus after it is inactive. And while inactive, simply do nothing each loop in your interval.

```
var IsFocused = true;
window.onfocus = function() {
    IsFocused = true;
}
window.onblur = function() {
    IsFocused = false;
}

var myinterval = setInterval(function() {

    if(!IsFocused) return;
    some dashboard update code here...

}, 10000);
```

Now if the issue is just that the interval is even running when the tab is inactive, you could just do this too:

```
var myinterval;
function StartInterval() {

    clearInterval(myinterval);
    myinterval = setInterval(function() {

        some dashboard update code here...

   }, 10000);

}
StartInterval(); //Start on first load.
window.onfocus = function() {

    StartInterval();

}
window.onblur = function() {

    clearInterval(myinterval);

}
```